# Apps ready for the 64-bit requirement by August 1, 2019

Tags: cordova, 32bit-64bit, mobile-development

Are apps made with cordova mobile development framework already 64-bit ready and compatible? Since we are developing in non-native code (Cordova), is the requirement related to us?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's already suppported if you don't use an old version of cordova, see

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/11/25/ios-64bit.html

Also Android 64 bit seems to be already supported, see [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/647)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
As I see this is for iOS, still i can´t find any relevant answer how is with android...